# change data when update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and when I make an insertion, I don't want to transfer data created, I want to put the sysdate. I have the next code:

```
create or replace procedure procedure1 as 
begin
  INSERT INTO tlp
            (given_name, 
             namel, 
             email, sysdate) 
SELECT first_name, 
       namel, 
       mail 
FROM   glob 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email ) 
         AND glob.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT namel 
                         FROM   tlp 
                         WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel ) 
             --AND glob.mail IS NULL 
             ); 
end procedure1;
```

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: sorry just sql and oracle sqldeveloper

Comment: add new column getdate() as sysdate in your select statement

Comment: i don't have permission to add a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `procedure` for `insert`, number of columns given for table `tlp` is `4` and `columns` selected from table `glob` is `3`.

If you want to `insert` `sysdate` for one column of table `tlp`, then mention the 
column name and add `sysdate` in the `select` statement.

Assuming the table structure of `tlp` is

```
tlp (
  given_name, 
  namel, 
  email, 
  date_created --if clmn name is not "date_created", then change it in the proc.
)
```

Now try this;

```
create or replace procedure 
procedure1 as 
begin
  INSERT INTO tlp (
    given_name, namel, 
    email, date_created
  ) 
  SELECT 
    first_name, namel, 
    mail, sysdate --note sysdate is given in select query
  FROM   glob 
  WHERE (
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT email 
      FROM   tlp 
      WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email 
    ) 
    AND glob.mail IS NOT NULL 
  ) OR ( 
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT namel 
      FROM   tlp 
      WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel 
    ) 
    --AND glob.mail IS NULL 
  ); 
end procedure1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace procedure procedure1 as 
begin
  INSERT INTO tlp
            (given_name, 
             namel, 
             email, sysdate) 
SELECT first_name, 
       namel, 
       mail,
       GETDATE() as  sysdate       
FROM   glob 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email ) 
         AND glob.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT namel 
                         FROM   tlp 
                         WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel ) 
             --AND glob.mail IS NULL 
             ); 
end procedure1;
```

Comment: add column in select getdate() as sysdate

Comment: it dosen't work and column I can't add because I don't have permission

Comment: If you have permission to alter table then you can perform : ALTER TABLE tlp ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tlp_sysdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [sysdate]